# Converse that reals are dense in R

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

Given that any r in R has a rational sequence that converges to it I want to show that between every 2 reals there is a rational. I want to show this just using the convergence fact only and not Archimedian property, I get stuck with then inequalities any help please.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, take a sequence of rationals converging to $a$ and use your assumption with $\epsilon=\frac{|a-b|}{2}$. You get rationals between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Hi, thanks but I did do that and get stuck with the inequalities. so wlog, take a<b then by assumption can fine a sequence of rationals {x_n} -> a, therefore for the choice (b-a)/2 we have for some m in N |x_n-a|<(b-a)/2 for all n>m. So then (3a-b)<2x_n<(b+a).  Can similarly get  an inequality using b and with different choices epsilon, taking epsilon to be b-a yields (2a-b)<x_n<b etc but the problem I have is manipulating the inequalities to get a rational between a and b, its probably some simply algebra but please can anyone offer some guidance. Thank you.